# Angular .ng-hide-remove animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have this CSS:

```
#platinumHeader.ng-hide-remove  {
-webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
-moz-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
-o-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
}
```

And this HMTL:

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top header-floating" data-ng-show="isHeader" id="platinumHeader">
        <div class="container">

          ...
        </div>
    </header>
```

But when my header is shown (i.e. isHeader is set to true) it just appears without animation.

But if I write CSS like this (without #platinumHeader selector):

```
.ng-hide-remove  {
-webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
-moz-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
-o-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
animation: fadeInDown 0.5s!important;
}
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tried something like this https://github.com/720kb/angular-fx but i guess there are tons of libs out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ngClass directive

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top header-floating" ng-class="{'ng-hide-remove' : isHeader}" data-ng-show="isHeader" id="platinumHeader">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't help

Comment: when you add the class .ng-hide-remove  in your code

Comment: Only issue I faced is that animation isn't triggered i.e. element just shows, it, isn't animated, but your answer gave me idea to create new class, just for test I called it 'bla', changed   CSS to: `#platinumHeader.bla  {...}` and HTML to: `ng-class="{'bla' : isHeader}"` and now it works. So I'm accepting yor answer as correct one